# Como tratar que a submissão de um formulário seja executada apenas uma vez?

Tags: javascript

Em um formulário do Method POST , quando eu clico no botão duas vezes rapidamente ele executa a submissão duas vezes.

Soluções com javascript ou com o spring framework .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Desabilite o botão após o primeiro clique, pois caso a solicitação demore o usuário terá a percepção que realmente foi enviada a requisição, e não poderá enviar outra.

```js
$('form#id').submit( function( e ) {
  $( this ).children( 'input[type=submit]' ).attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' );
  e.preventDefault(); 
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="id">
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno. é uma boa solução

Comment: @David, muito boa solução! Seria legal você editar o post adicionando o código para que caso o link do jsfiddle quebre mais pessoas possam ser ajudadas :D

Comment: Certo, já editaram pra mim, obrigado pela dica.