# Insert into com tempo de espera

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um formulario que a action dele envia para um arquivo.php que faz um insert no banco de dados com as informações passadas pelo formulario, e eu ja percebi que se eu clicar duas vezes bem rapido no botão submit ele envia dois registros identicos para o banco de dados, alguem sabe como faço um sistema de espera por exemplo se eu enviar um registro agora a 00:41:27 eu só vou poder enviar outro as 00:41:29 um timer de 2 segundos, ou ao clicar no botão submit uma vez ele bloqueia assim nao envia duas vezes o mesmo registro.

Comment: Da uma olhada em: [Como tratar que a submissão de um formulário seja executada apenas uma vez?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/86807/91)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode desabilitar o input com javascript:

```js
function funcao (obj) {
  obj.disabled = true; // desabilita o input
  console.log("qualquer código dentro da função.");
};
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Teste1" onclick="this.disabled=true" />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Teste2" onclick="funcao(this)" />
```

A `funcao` só é usada no click do Teste2. Vantagem que pode rodar vários códigos no mesmo evento, enquanto o Teste1 se limita apenas a desabilitar o botão.

Dentro da `funcao` você pode ainda usar este trecho de código:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    obj.disabled = false;
}, 3000)
```

Isso fará com que o botão volte a ser habilitado em 3 segundos.