# Desabilitar botão submit para não efetuar varias chamadas ao servidor

Tags: javascript, html, formulário

Estou tentando desabilitar o botão depois que clicar , para que não fique enviando os dados do formulário varias vezes se o usuário ficar clicando.

**meu botão**

```
<input type="submit" class="formButton" name="send" id="send" value="Enviar">
```

**meu js**

```
       $("#send").click(function(event){
            $(event.target).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        });
```

Quando clico no botão ele só desabilita o botão não envia

**Alteração**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){           
        $("#contato_1").submit(function(event){
            $("#send").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        });
    });
```

Com está alteração não está enviando o value do meu form , no meu php eu faço um teste `if (!isset($_POST['send'])) {`, não to sabendo porque parou de mandar, por isso não ta funcionando

Comment: Se você tirar este código JS o submit ocorre? Pergunto isso pois não sei o que você colocou no action do seu form.

Comment: sim , o meu formulário já estava funcionando , eu estou tentando resolver o problema do usuário poder clicar varias vezes

Comment: desative o `$("#send")` no evento `submit` do seu respectivo `form`.

Comment: e assim onsubmit="send.disabled=true;"  ?

Comment: adicionei uma resposta com mais informações sobre o problema e a possivel solução.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86806/como-tratar-que-a-submiss%C3%A3o-de-um-formul%C3%A1rio-seja-executada-apenas-uma-vez/86807#86807

Comment: Não funcionou aqui a solução dessa duplicata , não desabilitou

Comment: Eu sempre faço da maneira que fez, usando true false com uma variavel. Só que entenda, não somos um fórum. Se você tem uma resposta então poste como resposta, não coloque a resposta dentro do corpo da pergunta, isto é muito confuso. Somos um Q&A ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pagina HTML não irá enviar o `form` se o o `input[type="submit"]` estiver desativado.

Como o evento `click` do `input[type="submit"]` ocorre antes do `submit` do `form`, então você está a abortar de forma indireta o envio do `form`

então tente trocar o `$("#send").click()` pelo `$("#formID").submit()`;

```js
var formID = document.getElementById("formID");
var send = $("#send");

$(formID).submit(function(event){
  if (formID.checkValidity()) {
    send.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formID">
  <input type="text" required />
  <input type="submit" class="formButton" name="send" id="send" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

como altenativa ao método citado, podemos tentar soluções alternativas:

## 1 - bloquear o button enviar com uma div:

```js
var formID = document.getElementById("formID");
var send = document.getElementById("send");

var onSendClick = function (event) {
  if (formID.checkValidity()) {
    event.target.parentNode.classList.add("disabled");
    event.target.removeEventListener("click", onSendClick);
  }
}

send.addEventListener("click", onSendClick);
```

```css
#containerEnviar {
  position: relative;
}

#containerEnviar #blockEnviar {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}


#containerEnviar.disabled #blockEnviar {
  display: block;
}

#containerEnviar.disabled #send {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<form id="formID">
  <input type="text" required />
  <div id="containerEnviar">    
    <input type="submit" class="formButton" name="send" id="send" value="Enviar">
    <div id="blockEnviar"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

No exemplo acima, a `div#blockEnviar` irá impedir que o `input#send` seja clicado, de forma preventiva o evento click associado ao `input#send` tambem está sendo removido.

**2 - Envio por AJAX**

```js
var formID = document.getElementById("formID");
var send = document.getElementById("send");

formID.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
  if (formID.checkValidity()) {
    var formData = new FormData(formID);
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
    httpRequest.open(formID.method, formID.action, false);
    httpRequest.addEventListener("readystatechange", function(event) {
      if (httpRequest.readyState == 4) {
        if (httpRequest.status == 200) {
          alert("Envio do Formulario realizado com sucesso");
        } else {
          alert("Ocorreu um erro ao enviar o Formulario");
          send.disabled = false; //posibilitar uma nova tentativa;
        }
      }
    });
    
    send.disabled = true;
    httpRequest.send(formData);    
  }
  
  //impedir o envio sincrono do form
  return false;
});
```

```html
<form id="formID" action="minha_url" method="post">
  <input id="input1" name="input1" type="text" required />
  <input type="submit" class="formButton" name="send" id="send" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Aqui a sua requisição é feita de forma asincrona, então você deverá tratar o retorno da requisição para tomar uma decisão, seja para informar o sucesso da mesma e realizar um redirecionamento ou para informar um erro.

Comment: meu formulário tem uns teste , ai tem hora que não envia por falta de algum campo preenchido e com isso ai o botão fica desabilitado se não enviar , como posso habilitar se voltar

Comment: não ta enviando desse jeito :/ , vou atualizar a pergunta do jeito que ficou

Comment: @IlgnerdeOliveira não vás mudando a pergunta com ideias das respostas. Assim as respostas deixam de fazer sentido...

Comment: @IlgnerdeOliveira, Se estiver utilizando uma validação por HTML5, você pode checar se o form é valido antes de desativar o button usando o metodo `checkValidity` no form... você pode conferir a resposta para ver a implementação.

Comment: @TobyMosque antes de colocar este js meu formulário estava enviando o value do input, preciso dele para fazer um teste no php. quando eu coloquei o js ele para de enviar este value, sabe o porque isso acontece?

Comment: @IlgnerdeOliveira, acredito que o seu problema inicial já está resolvido, agora você está com problemas para receber um dado especifico no PHP (como programador C# que alimenta um certo desdenho pelo PHP, não posso te ajudar neste ponto), mas como opção, você pode tentar impedir o reenvio do formulario de outra forma, como por exemplo com um bloqueio da tela, uso de uma flag ou uma requisição AJAX.

Comment: @IlgnerdeOliveira, adicionei uma solução de contorno para os eu problema, apesar de não acreditar que seja a solução ideal, ela deve resolver o seu problema.

Comment: Oque você alterou foi a forma de desabilitar ne? com a sua solução estava desabilitando , mais não está enviando uma informação que preciso no php

Comment: @IlgnerdeOliveira na solução #1, não estou mais desativando do `input#send`, estou apenas tornando impossivel que ele seja clicado (existe uma div invisivel cobrindo o mesmo)... na solução #2, estou enviando o formulario de forma asincrona, então não há problema em o `input#send` está desativado.

Comment: @TobyMosque coloquei a solução que funcionou aqui la na pergunta

Answer (score 2):

Sugiro mudares a logica. Penso que durante a execução da callback do evento `click` ainda é possivel impedir o `submit`, que deve vir depois do clique.

Ou corres esse código no final do submit, ou podes mudar para esta lógica que usa uma flag para impedir submeter duas vezes:

```
var ativo = false;
$("#aTuaForm").on('submit', function(event) {
    if (ativo) preventDefault();
    ativo = true;
    var xhr;

    var timeout = setTimeout(function() { // caso o ajax não corra bem
        xhr.abort();
        ativo = false; // preparado para um novo envio
    }, 5000); // cancela depois de 5000

    xhr = $.ajax({
        url: "/o/teu/endereco",
        success: function(result) {
            ativo = false; // preparado para um novo envio
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            // o resto do teu código
        }
    });
});
```

Se quiseres, como o [@TobyMosque](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105466/quando-clico-no-bot%C3%A3o-submit-n%C3%A3o-envia-os-dados-do-formulario/105470?noredirect=1#comment216551_105470) referiu também podes usar a callback `error` do jQuery. Nesse caso não precisas do timeout:

```
error: function(){
    ativo = false;
}
```

Comment: Sergio, não seria melhor setar a flag `ativo` para `false` no `error` no `ajax`?

Comment: @TobyMosque essa também é uma boa maneira. Vou juntar, obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Se você pretende enviar os dados do form, processar e receber algum retorno, então você deve desabilitar o botão no beforeSend e após receber o retorno no success você deve habilitar o botão novamente, ou pode redirecionar para outra página. Acredito que o código abaixo pode te ajudar.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery("#send").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();

            codigo   = jQuery('input[id="nome"]').val();//campo no form

            jQuery.ajax({
                url: 'teste_botao.php', 
                dataType: 'html',
                data: {par01: codigo},
                type: 'POST',
                beforeSend: function(){
                    //jQuery('#insere-aqui').html(iconCarregando);
                    jQuery('#send').attr('disabled', 'disabled');//desabilito
                },
                complete: function(){
                    jQuery(iconCarregando).remove();
                },
                success: function(data, textStatus) {
                    jQuery('#insere-aqui').html('');
                    jQuery('#insere-aqui').html(data);
                    jQuery('#send').removeAttr('disabled');//habilito
                },
                error: function(xhr,er) {
                    jQuery('#insere-aqui').html('Error ' + xhr.status + ' - ' + xhr.statusText + '<br />Tipo de erro: ' + er +'')
                }       
            });
    });

});
```

**EXEMPLO Com serialize()**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
        var iconCarregando = $('<img src="../icon/mini.gif" class="icon" /> <span class="destaque">Carregando. Por favor aguarde...</span>');
    $('#form_um').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var serializeDados = $('#form_um').serialize();

    $.ajax({
            url: 'exemplo-serialize.php', 
            dataType: 'html',
            type: 'POST',
            data: serializeDados,
            beforeSend: function(){
            $('#insere_aqui').html(iconCarregando);
            $('#send').attr('disabled', 'disabled');//desabilito
            },
            complete: function() {
            $(iconCarregando).remove();
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus) {
            $('#insere_aqui').html('<p>' + data + '</p>');
            $('#send').removeAttr('disabled');//habilito
            },
            error: function(xhr,er) {
                $('#mensagem_erro').html('<p class="destaque">Error ' + xhr.status + ' - ' + xhr.statusText + '<br />Tipo de erro: ' + er +'</p>')
            }       
        });
    }); 
})
</script>
```

Comment: Assim só está enviando o nome , e o resto dos dados do formulario

Comment: o código é um exemplo, o restante dos campos você adiciona, a ideia era desabilitar o botão, mas para enviar o form todo você pode usar o método serialize().

Comment: @IlgnerdeOliveira, deixei um exemplo com o serialize().